# Binary tree in which each node is the sum of two children

Tags: python, recursion, tree

I wrote in python a class for Binary Search Tree

my intent is writing a code that allows me to pass from this input:

```
       3
    /    \
  10      9
 /  \
1   88
```

to this output:

```
       111
     /    \
   99      9
  /  \
 1    88
```

As you can see, each node's data is the sum of the integers of its subtree

What can I do?

Comment: why did your 88 turn into 8 ...

Comment: it looks like you just need to traverse the tree and recursively collect the required amount for its children at each node: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41622174/inorder-binary-tree-traversal-using-python

Comment: in output how a 99 == 1 + 8 ?

Comment: @sahasrara62 I edited, it was 88

Comment: @iqmaker I edited, it was 88, my error